# Android background drawable image cripples animation performance

Tags: android

I have a layout somewhat like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:bakcground:"#333">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" android:src="@drawable/some_image"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've coded a support class which animates `img` by calling `ImageView.setX` and `.setRotation` based on user input (finger swiping, fetching the coordinate). This works fine as long as the background of the RelativeLayout is a single color. I'm getting 30+ FPS on my HTC One.

Then I change the background of the RelativeLayout to an image resource and everything changes. The performance is crippeled! I'm looking at <1 FPS. The  image is a 1280x768 PNG image on about 1.2MB.

Any explanation to this? I'm assuming hardware accelleration is enabled. Doing a performance analytics in DDMS monitor shows me that most of the action is happening in `android.view.GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList`

How can I improve performance and still have a background image?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=U4Bk5rmIpic#t=2719

Comment: Isn't it beacuse of the weight of the image? Android default max. weight to render is 2MB. Do you really need it to be PNG? Otherwise, try to make it JPEG and lower the weight... something under 0.5 MB. For sure you will get and improved performance...